# Dialog box doing more than just hiding itself on close

Tags: c#, winforms, dialog

According to the MSDN document, the close operation on a form shown with [ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7ykbedk.aspx) should only cause the form to be hidden. Subsequent calls to ShowDialog() will unhide the form.

This doesn't seem to be case, exactly. I have a form with a tree view on it. The check states are preserved between calls to ShowDialog() but any node expansion the user has done is reset back to its default state. Also, the Load event is being executed every time as well. So it seems to be doing more than just "hiding" the form. Anyone have any idea what's up?

Thanks

Comment: Let's see some code please! I bet you are recreating the form instead of reusing an instance.

Comment: This sounds like you have wired up an Event improperly can you show what code you have in regards to the issues you are reporting?

Comment: This is normal behavior.  Winforms is capable of re-creating the native windows from the stored state in the controls.  But TreeView is difficult, it has way too much state associated with it.  Winforms doesn't try to preserve the state of the nodes.  It will thus restore with all the nodes collapsed again when it re-creates the native window.

Comment: If I was recreating the form neither state of the check boxes nor items in the `TreeView` would be preserved. They are. The only event I'm wiring up in the form is Load. It's quite strange.

Comment: @HansPassant: Is there anything you would suggest to keep the state preserved? I suppose I could run through the tree and store the states myself on close.

Answer (score 1):

I've experienced this issue myself.  For some reason, calling `Form.Hide` or setting `visible = false` on a modal form will call `Form.Close` in at least some cases.  To work around it I set the opacity to zero.  You can also use `Form.Show` instead.

It is somewhat intuitive if you imagine the behavior of a modal dialogue.  It blocks the parent window.  So if you hide it then there would be no active window for the user to interact with.  FWIW, I think the behavior should have been that the parent becomes active again.  That's just not always the case.

Comment: If you set the opacity to 0, wouldn't the form still 'be there' and still capture events and stuff, as in you won't be able to click through it? (this is a curiosity thing... I really don't know what happens)

Comment: @nekizalb Yes indeed.  In my particular case I had multiple windows so this was not an issue.  However, depending on what exactly the OP is doing this could be an issue which requires them to do more work (such as use the alternative solution).